# Why persist () are lazily evaluated in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I understood the point that in Spark there are 2 types of operations

1. Transformations
2. Actions

Transformations like `map()`, `filter()` are evaluated lazily. So, that optimization can be done on Action execution. For example, if I execute action `first()` then Spark will optimize to read only the first line.

But why `persist()` operation is evaluated lazily? Because either way I go, eagerly or lazily, it will persist the entire RDD as per Storage level.

Can you please detail to me why `persist()` is transformation instead of action?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For starters eager persistence would pollute a whole pipeline. `cache` or `persist` only expresses intention. It doesn't mean we'll ever get to the point when RDD is materialized and can be actually cached. Moreover there are contexts where data is cached automatically.

> Because either ways I go, eagerly or lazily, it is going to persist entire RDD as per Storage level.

It is not exactly true. Thing is, `persist` is not persistent. As it is clearly stated [in the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) for `MEMORY_ONLY` persistence level:

> *If the RDD does not fit in memory, some partitions will not be cached and will be recomputed on the fly each time they're needed.*

With `MEMORY_AND_DISK` remaining data is stored to the disk but still can be evicted if there is not enough memory for subsequent caching. What is even more important:

> *Spark automatically monitors cache usage on each node and drops out old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) fashion.*

You can also argue that `cache` / `persist` is semantically different from Spark actions which are executed for specific IO side-effects. `cache` is more a hint for a Spark engine that we may want to reuse this piece of code later.

Answer (score 6):

If you have some data that you might or might not use, making `persist()` eager would be inefficient. A normal Spark transformation corresponds to a `def` in Scala. A persist turns it into a `lazy val`.

Answer (score 1):

persist is confusing name as it does not persist beyond your context lifetime.

persist is the same as cache. Data is cached the first time it is computed so that if you use your RDD in another computation , the results are not recalculated.

Comment: False they are not the same, `persist` saves on disk but `cache` saves in the mem, furthermore `persist` has several ways to work on `scala` and `java` APIs.

Comment: I stand (partially corrected): cache() = persist() =  persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

It still a way to temporally cache intermediate computations. It is only done when needed thus it is a lazy operation

Comment: That's my question "Why make persist() call lazy?" Because eventually it is going to store (for that context lifetime) RDD as per storage level (like MEMORY_ONLY, DISK_ONLY, etc). In other transformations, I agree that we can achieve cost optimization with laziness.

Comment: I don t know whether there are underlining advantages since you presumably going to use the RDD but  there is also no reason not wait