# Is Spark's df.cache() executed eagerly or lazily?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using pyspark in my work. In this article https://unraveldata.com/to-cache-or-not-to-cache/, it says cache is not an action. However, when I run a cache function on an RDD, it takes a lot of time. And the spark UI shows there are some activate jobs called `cache at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0`. So is cache an action?

Comment: [Why persist () are lazily evaluated in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34438670/8371915)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951939/caching-ordered-spark-dataframe-creates-unwanted-job

Comment: @RaphaelRoth thanks for your answer

Answer (score 6):

**Cache is a lazy action**. That means when the variable  that is constructed from cache is accessed it is going to compute it then. So it is showing it takes time.

When computation is called on it, all the data is moving to ram. Once data is available in ram computations are performed.

Comment: I have the same opinion. However when I run my program in jupyter notebook. My code is like `df = ...` and then I run `df.cache()`, the second step cost a lot of time and in spark web UI, there are some activate jobs called `cache at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0`. This really confused me, so I ask this question.

Comment: Can you post the web ui screen shots

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @RaphaelRoth provides the answer I need.

Comment: Technically it's a lazy *operation*, as actions are eager by definition.